# Filesystemwatcher for file open notification

Tags: c#, asp.net

please help me with the way to have a count for the number of times a file (.txt or .pdf) has been opened by user with the help of filesystemwatcher.

even after setting  NotifyFilter-property to LastAccess, and catching the Changed-event. Like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher lWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop", "myfile.txt");    
lWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;    
lWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(HandlerWatcherChanged);    

void HandlerWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // file has been accessed
}
```

I have enabled Last Access time updates if necessary.
still I am not able to get that.

Comment: Did you remember to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`?

Comment: yes i have set EnableRaisingEvents to true

Comment: At the windows level, you could turn on auditing on this file and then a security log event would be recorded each time the file is e.g. read. File System Watcher isn't 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is related to this:

[filesystemwatcherchanged-event-does-it-fire-when-a-file-is-accessed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5752e234-6429-456c-bbd0-a2bbf49c5914/filesystemwatcherchanged-event-does-it-fire-when-a-file-is-accessed)

**EDIT:**

Failing that try the following code:

```
FileSystemWatcher lWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop", "*.txt");    
lWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;    
lWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
lWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(HandlerWatcherChanged);    

void HandlerWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.FullPath.Contains("mfile.txt")) 
         return; //do work here
}
```

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question, please add that information.

Comment: i have  Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate to 0 and the access time of the file is getting changed when i open the file..

Comment: after using NotifyFilters.LastAccess it has even stopped catching the event for modifying the file ..

Comment: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/

I'm sure this is doing the same regedit that you have done.  Perhaps you need to restart after making the change?? (That old chesnut!)

Comment: after doing the same i have restarted and i didn't get the result