# check in realtime an external process when open a file

Tags: c#, c++, file-access

I need to check in realtime if a specific process try to read a wav of flac file.

I hare created a routine with 2 parameters: the process name, and the file that try to open:

```
        public static bool Scan(string ProcessName,string TextToFind)
    {

        // getting minimum & maximum address
        SYSTEM_INFO sys_info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
        GetSystemInfo(out sys_info);

        int MatchCount=0;

        IntPtr proc_min_address = sys_info.minimumApplicationAddress;
        IntPtr proc_max_address = sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress;

        // saving the values as long ints so I won't have to do a lot of casts later
        long proc_min_address_l = (long)proc_min_address;
        long proc_max_address_l = (long)proc_max_address;

        Process[] Arrprocess = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);

        if (Arrprocess.Length == 0) return false;

        // notepad better be runnin'
        Process process = Arrprocess[0];

        // opening the process with desired access level
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

        // this will store any information we get from VirtualQueryEx()
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_basic_info = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();

        int bytesRead = 0;  // number of bytes read with ReadProcessMemory

        // long milliseconds_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

        while (proc_min_address_l < proc_max_address_l)
        {
            // 28 = sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)
            VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, proc_min_address, out mem_basic_info, 28);

            // if this memory chunk is accessible
            if (mem_basic_info.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE && mem_basic_info.State == MEM_COMMIT && (mem_basic_info.lType == MEM_MAPPED || mem_basic_info.lType == MEM_PRIVATE))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[mem_basic_info.RegionSize];

                // read everything in the buffer above
                ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, mem_basic_info.BaseAddress, buffer, mem_basic_info.RegionSize, ref bytesRead);

                string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                if (result.Contains(TextToFind))
                    return true;

            }

            // move to the next memory chunk
            proc_min_address_l += mem_basic_info.RegionSize;
            proc_min_address = new IntPtr(proc_min_address_l);
        }


        return false;
    }
```

this code work only the first time, because when the process close the flac file, the string keep in memory until the process will close.

I need to check every time (with precision of milliseconds) the process try to load the file that I pass as parameter.

I don't known if i'am in the right way ...

Can someone suggest me a code (in c# or c++) that detect in realtime if a process x try to read a file name y ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Windows provides methods to let you know when files are opened/edited/renamed/etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/file-system-operation-notifications

Comment: many many thanks ! this seem what I need, becouse I don't have much excperience in c++ (I'am a c# developer), do you known if there a ready source that I can do a "copy and paste" ? I have traied to paste it on blank c++ project but there are many compiled errors. thank agin.

Comment: There is a full example at the bottom of the page I linked to.

Comment: Also, please accept this answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Also here’s a C# answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137255/filesystemwatcher-for-file-open-notification

Comment: thank you for this, but I have already tried with "FileSystemWatcher" with some result of the link you have post: not work. C++ seem use "PrjStartVirtualizing" that is very interested solution but I don't find a small project that use it .